# Trigger with IF and JOIN in SQL Server 'could not be bound'

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I wrote the trigger but I get an error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure quest_field_key_af, Line 5
>   The multi-part identifier "query_creator.field_key" could not be bound.

This should work, it's almost complite and i don't have any idea how to fix it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER SAMPLE_NAME
ON [dbo].[QC]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    IF ([QC].field_key != 'blank_blank')
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[CQ]
        SET [CQ].quest_field_key = (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), [CQ].quest_id)+'_'+RIGHT('000'+ CAST([CF].field_no AS VARCHAR(3)),3))
        FROM dbo.query_creator
        INNER JOIN query_field ON [CQ].field_key = [CF].field_key
        WHERE [QC].status = 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[QC]
        SET quest_field_key = (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), [QC].quest_id)+'_'+RIGHT('000'+ CAST(no AS VARCHAR(3)),3)+'b')
        FROM dbo.QC
END;
```

Please help me to fix it or give me an idea for something other that will work.

Comment: IF ([QC].field_key != 'blank_blank') will not work in a trigger, you have to loop through the inserted table and do this for each updated or inserted record from the inserted table

Comment: This has the appearance of being a challenge due to an improperly defined key structure. Have you considered using a composite key instead of smashing multiple pieces of data into a single column like this? What you have is violating 1NF and can be super ugly to deal with if any of the data changes. Even if you stick with this design do NOT resort to looping for this. There is nothing here that can't be done in a single update statement with a left join and a case expression.

Comment: So what do you recommended to me?

Answer (score 0):

This should be close to what you need.  Updating the records that were inserted based on the logic in your if code.

```
CREATE TRIGGER SAMPLE_NAME
ON [dbo].[QC]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    Update QC Set [CQ].quest_field_key = 
            Case When [QC].field_key != 'blank_blank' And [QC].status = 1 Then CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), [CQ].quest_id)+'_'+RIGHT('000'+ CAST([CF].field_no AS VARCHAR(3)),3)
                 Else CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), [QC].quest_id)+'_'+RIGHT('000'+ CAST(no AS VARCHAR(3)),3)+'b'
                 End
        From [dbo].[QC]
        INNER JOIN query_field QF ON [QC].field_key = [QF].field_key
        INNER JOIN inserted I On I.(your match key) = QC.(your match key)

END;
```

Comment: What should i do with that (your match key) ?

Comment: It is the unique key on your table, preferably a primary key.  It matches the inserted table (rows inserted or updated) which is temporary inside the trigger with the actual table data that was updated.